# how to iterate over list of items in html with list constructed in a javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS that I prepare my div like this:

JS

```
function foo()
{
     const a = 4;
     const b = 'Hello'

    document.getElementById('id-a').innerHTML = a;
    document.getElementById('id-b').innerHTML = b;
}
```

and later in my html I do below and it presents the values.

```
<h1><div id='id-a'></div></h1>
<h1><div id='id-b'></div></h1>
```

So far so good. Now I wish to have a list of items and iterate over such that:

```
function bar()
{
      var myList = [];
      for (i=0; i<10; i++)
      {
           var d = {"i":i, "s":'this is my stiring'}
           myList.push(d);
      }
}
```

Question, how do I iterate this over a table that looks like this?

```
    <table>
        <tr>
        <th>index</th>
        <th>string</th>
      <tr>
           //here must come a for loop to iterate over the 'myList'
        <td>?</td>
        <td>?</td>
      </tr>
```

I couldn't figure out what is the JS or JQuery needed to iterate in a different html file (like the process I initially presented).

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by looping over the table and what do the `div`s have to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you can try this

```js
function bar()
{     let tbBody = '';
      for (i=0; i<10; i++)
      {
         tbBody+=`<tr><td>${i}</td><td>this is my string</td></tr>`
      }
      
      document.getElementById("tb-body").innerHTML = tbBody
}

bar();
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  <th>index</th>
  <th>string</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tb-body">
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add 'A' and 'B' class names to the tags you want to loop through, you can use `document.getElementsByClassName([your_class_name])`. The function would look something like this:

```
<table>
        <tr>
        <th>index</th>
        <th>string</th>
      <tr>
           //here must come a for loop to iterate over the 'myList'
        <td class="my-list-class-a">?</td>
        <td class="my-list-class-b">?</td>
      </tr>
```

```
function bar()
{
      var myListA = document.getElementByClassName('my-list-class-a');
      var myListB = document.getElementByClassName('my-list-class-b');
      for (i=0; i<10; i++)
      {
           myListA[i].innerHTML = i;
           myListB[i].innerHTML = 'this is my string';
      }
}
```